# Passing prop onPress in same screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, state, expo, react-props

In my react-native app i have two buttons in the same screen which should trigger the same function onPress and pass ID prop on the same press, they're triggering the function but the difference is that they should pass different props but it always returns undefined, here is the code:

```
 myFunction = () => {
    // function here
    id = this.props.id
  }

<Button onPress={this.myFunction}
id="1" />
<Button onPress={this.myFunction} 
id="2"/>
```

Comment: Well, you are passing the `id` as a prop to the Button component, not to `myFunction`. Not that this will solve your problem, but while we're at it..: use `onPress` and not `onpress`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like

```
 myFunction = (id) => {
    // function here
  }
<Button onPress={() => { this.myFunction(1)}}/>
<Button onPress={() => { this.myFunction(2)}}/>
```